# Android Mobile number and Wi-Fi MAC address

Tags: android

I want to know Mobile number and Wi-Fi-Address .Howis this possible.Can anyone Help me

Answer (score 2):

try this for Mobile Number

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
// get IMEI
String imei = tm.getDeviceId();
String phone = tm.getLine1Number();
```

but its not always reliable on for example non phone device. You will also need to add permision "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE".

for MAC address

```
WifiManager wfManager;
    WifiInfo wifiinfo; 
wfManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiinfo = wfManager.getConnectionInfo();
String MAC = wifiinfo.getMacAddress();
```

Comment: I tried this method for mobile number.But It does not show mobile number .Thanks for WI FI ......

Comment: and plz ask your all issue in one question. dont create many question for minor issue.

Comment: Sorry But I am not good in English.I think I did not expresses my question .Actually your Wi-Fi is working .But For number is show nothing.I am not unable to show mobile number.Can you please send this code

Comment: I didnt tried Phone Number i just checked your last question and you accept your right answer so add that answer here

Answer (score 0):

```
public  String getMAC() {
    wifimanager= (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    wifiinfo = wifimanager.getConnectionInfo();
   MAC=wifiinfo.getMacAddress();
    System.out.println("MAC address info---- "+MAC);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MAC address:"+MAC , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(MAC==null){
        MAC="1A:DC:5C:8E:15:7B";
    }

    return MAC;
}
```